# "Down-Closed", "Down Ideal", Something Else?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, terminology, discrete-mathematics, order-theory

Let $X$ be an a set and let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$ satisfying the following property:

> If $A$ and $A^\prime$ are subsets of $X$ with $A \in \mathcal{C}$ and $A^\prime \subseteq A$, then $A^\prime \in \mathcal{C}$.

I have heard this described variously as "$\mathcal{A}$ is down-closed" and "$\mathcal{A}$ is a down ideal", but neither of these phrases seem very prevalent on the internet. Is there a more common name for this property?

Comment: Somewhat confusing to use the same letter (albeit in a different font) for the set and its members.  Do you mean $A' \in {\cal A}$?

Comment: This reminds me of dedekend cuts.

Comment: How about "downward closed"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael My explanation was incomplete because I didn't define an ambient set. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Isn't closure under unions also required for an ideal?

Comment: @QuinnCulver: I withdraw my previous comment :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28order_theory%29) indicates, you're missing a condition required for the given collection to be an 'ideal'. As [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_set) indicates, the terms 'downward closed', 'down set', 'lower set', et al. are appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The term "downset" is sometimes used.  See e.g. Anderson, "Combinatorics of Finite Sets".

Comment: Google books [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=RjDd4RaqrIwC&q=downset&pg=PA87&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=downset).

Answer (score 2):

In the case where $\mathcal{C}$ consists of finite sets only, $\mathcal{C}$ is an [abstract simplicial complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex).

Comment: According to the wikipedia article, this is in the case that $\mathcal C$ consists of finite sets only, right?

Comment: Good point. I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In "The Probabilistic Method", Alon and Spencer call such a collection "[monotone decreasing](http://books.google.com/books?id=V8YgNioxF6AC&q=monotone+decreasing&q=monotone%20decreasing)".

Comment: Sorry for answering my own question. I found this reference after posting and thought it should be included.

Comment: As are the terms I listed, 'monotone decreasing' is a general order-theoretic term. Note that 'decreasing' was listed in the link I provided.